# Getting started with coding aspect of ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are there *any assignments online or anything* as such that help me(beginner) become **proficient in using ROS environment,its commands,programming & also things like RViz , Simulator & TurtleBot** without actually needing any hardware aspect of making a robot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265023/getting-started-with-coding-aspect-of-ros/) by [akhilkathi](https://answers.ros.org/users/30211/akhilkathi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-06-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-28**:
Just making sure that you have seen [wiki/Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials). That would only cover the basics, but should give you a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here's an [official cheat sheet (for Indigo)](https://github.com/ros/cheatsheet/releases) which is three pages covering information from creating and working with workspaces, different tools, and more. Here's a direct link to the [PDF version of the cheat sheet](https://github.com/ros/cheatsheet/releases/download/0.0.1/ROScheatsheet_catkin.pdf).

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0